# Knex.js - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: knex.js

I'm trying to build database migrations with the Knex.js query builder, however I get the following error relating to the foreign key relationship:

```
Knex:warning - migrations failed with error: alter table `presentations` add constraint presentations_owner_id_foreign foreign key (`owner_id`) references `users` (`user_id`) - ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE: Can't create table `application`.`#sql-35c_6a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

This is the migration for the `presentations` table:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.createTable('presentations', function(table) {
      table.increments('presentation_id');
      table.string('title', 255);
      table.integer('owner_id');
      table.boolean('is_live');
      table.timestamps();

      table.foreign('owner_id').references('user_id').inTable('users');
    })
  ]);
};
```

And this is the migration for the `users` table:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
      table.increments('user_id');
      table.string('first_name');
      table.string('last_name');
      table.string('email_address').unique();
      table.string('password');

      ...

      table.timestamps();
    })
  ]);
};
```

Could the differing data types be at fault? I am trying to establish a relationship between an `integer` and an `increments` type.

Comment: I ran the basic code against an SQLite DB and it worked okay. I didn't try running it within a migration process though. The constraint worked properly preventing invalid data entry too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `users.user_id` and `presentations.owner_id` have different types.

```js
// users table
table.increments('user_id'); // generates an unsigned integer

// presentations table
table.integer('owner_id'); // generates a signed integer
```

The solution is to make the column that references the primary key explicitly unsigned.

```js
table.integer('owner_id').unsigned();

// or: create column and relation in one go
table.integer('owner_id').unsigned().notNullable().references('users.user_id');
```

See also: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/245#issuecomment-619245125

By the way: SQLite either does not care or there are different types at play. We only discovered this later when we started testing against MariaDB.